# How to prevent trailing zeros from being removed using StreamWriter

Tags: vb.net

I am using streamwriter to save data from a 12 column DataGridView. The last Six columns contain numbers with 3 decimal places. When I write the numbers like 23.567 every thing is fine but if the number is 3.720 the trailing zero is removed. I would like to keep any trailing zeros. What do I need to change?

```
For x As Integer = 0 To Dgv0.Rows.Count - 1
    For y As Integer = 0 To Dgv0.Columns.Count - 1
        WriteFile.Write(Dgv0(y, x).Value)   
           If y <> Dgv0.Columns.Count - 1 Then
               WriteFile.Write(",")
           End If
    Next
        WriteFile.WriteLine()
Next
```

Comment: Try converting you data to `String` instead of using `Decimal` values.

Comment: Use CDec(Dgv0(y, x).Value).ToString("F3")

Comment: *"The last Six columns contain numbers with 3 decimal places"*. No they don't, as there's no such thing. If it's a number then it just has the value it has. Leading and trailing zeroes are meaningless. They are simply representations, which requires the data to be `Strings`. It's not the `StreamWriter` doing anything. It's just that you are relying on an implicit conversion from `Decimal` to `String`. If you want a specific representation then you have to specify it, which is what @HansPassant has shown. If you just call `ToString` without the format then you'll get the same result as now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as follows: Note all 12 columns are to be saved in a csv file. The first 6 columns are to be saved as strings which they are. The last 6 columns are to be saved as 3 digit decimal numbers which they are, so the first order of business is to separate the last 6 columns from the first 6 and then format as needed. Here is the code that works.

```
       For x As Integer = 0 To Dgv0.Rows.Count - 1
            For y As Integer = 0 To Dgv0.Columns.Count - 1
                If y > 5 And y < 12 Then
                    WriteFile.Write(Format(CDec(Dgv0(y, x).Value), "N3"))
                Else
                    WriteFile.Write(Dgv0(y, x).Value)
                End If                                      
                If y <> Dgv0.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                    WriteFile.Write(",")
                End If
            Next
            WriteFile.WriteLine()
        Next
```